# Receiving RF signal in an android application

Tags: android

I am working on a Help alert android application for which I need to detect the RF signal from my android application, I had googled but not find anything concrete, Please can anybody help in this case about the Receive RF signal in android.

Answer (score 0):

Do provide more information of the data you are looking for or on the application your are making.

You can try referring to getGsmSignalStrength () ;

Additional information can be found at 
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html][1]